# Multiple level routes, cannot access parent parameters

Tags: angular, router-outlet

I am managing groups and their members. To do so, i've created two different modules, one for the groups and the other for the members. I'm loading the routes for the members by lazy loading. Here is my groups-routing module :

`const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'groups',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: GroupListComponent,
      },
      {
        path: ':id',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            component: GroupDetailComponent,
          },
          {
            path: 'edit',
            component: GroupFormComponent
          },
          {
            path: 'members',
            loadChildren: 'app/groups/members/members.module#MembersModule',
          }
        ],
      },
    ],
  }`

With this version, everything is working as expected.

- In my `GroupDetailComponent` and `GroupFormComponent`, I get my parameter with `this.route.params.subscribe(params...` and it is at params['id'].
- In my `MemberDetailComponent` (/groups/:id/members/:member_id), I get my parameters with `this.route.snapshot.parent.params`

However, I now want to add a tab menu to manage the group and its members by switching tabs, so I've updated my group-routing to this :

`const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'groups',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: GroupListComponent,
      },
      {
        path: ':id',
        component: GroupComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            redirectTo: 'detail',
            pathMatch: 'full',
          },
          {
            path: 'detail',
            component: GroupDetailComponent,
          },
          {
            path: 'edit',
            component: GroupFormComponent
          },
          {
            path: 'members',
            loadChildren: 'app/groups/members/members.module#MembersModule',
          }
        ],
      },
    ],
  }`

Where i just display a menu in the `GroupComponent`.

- Now to get my group id in my `GroupDetailComponent`, I need to use `this.route.snapshot.parent.params`
- However I am not able to get my group id in components from my `MembersModule`

Am i doing something wrong ? I've just added a "shared" module that is just a menu for the group.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Console log out (this.route.snapshot). It will be buried in there somewhere. I had this exact same issue, and had to look through all the nodes to find it :)

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for your answer.
I've searched in all of this.route (in the params, snapshot and parent) and i can't find the parameter. I could get it by parsing the URL I have '/groups/1/members'  but it is not really convenient.